# Dialog Widget automatically closed on selectionIndexchanged of dropdownlist in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

in my page i am using dialog widget as popup window. popup contain one drowdownlist (autopostBack:true).on selectedindexchanged  popup closed automatically. please help me out to avoid this.

```
<input type="button" id="opener" value="OPEN" />
<div id="dialog" title="Filters">
<asp:DropDownList ID="update_lb_name" runat="server"  style="width:200px" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="fvr_selectedIndex_changed" ></asp:DropDownList>
<input type="button" id="closer" value="CLOSE" />
</div>
 jquery code:
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog({

            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            dialogClass: 'no-close',
            draggable: false,
            minWidth: 500
        });
    });
});
$("#opener").click(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
});
$("#closer").click(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog("close");
});
```

**css code:**

```
<STYLE type="text/css">
     .no-close .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {display: none }
</STYLE>
```

Answer (score 0):

<del>Use `return false;` in your function it will work.</del>

```
$("#opener").click(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    return false;
});
```

or use `event.preventDefault();` as below

```
$("#opener").click(function (event) {
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

### Edit 1

as you are using a dropdown list with autopostback to true. so it will do the postback and your pop-up will be closed.

You need to set some values before postback so that after postback you open the popup again.

and example could be use a `hidden filed` and set value before postback and use this value to open popup again.

Comment: thnk u for replying. but both the above two ideas are not working.

Comment: i beginner to asp.net. i don't know about 'hidden filed'. so kindly guide me